# ListView display error saying "String[] array" in every row C#

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, listview

So I want to display some information in a ListView. But I got a very weird outcome. The listView is showing "String[] Array" in every cell.
The information I want to display is stored in a array string.

[output of my listView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jx5V.jpg)

C#

```
public void addTagDataListView(string[] content)
    {


        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            ListViewItem lsi = new ListViewItem();
            lsi.Content = content;
            //lsi.Content = new string[] { content[0].ToString(), content[1].ToString(), content[2].ToString(), content[3].ToString() };
            lsvData.Items.Add(lsi);
        }));
    }
```

XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="lsvData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="266" Margin="10,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="50"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="PosX" Width="120"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="PosY" Width="120"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Time stamp" Width="200"/>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: You have no value `Binding`s in `GridViewColumn', add some. Then, this should work.

Comment: Look up binding and have a class that has the 4 properties

Answer (score -2):

The text shown on the rows of the listview usually is the item's ToString() function. It seems as if you've added a string array instead of a string to each row. The string array's ToString() will return "string[] array"

Comment: And do you know how to fix this? 
lsi.Content = content[0]; 
that works, but the entire row is full of the value of content[0]

Comment: Sounds like this function is called once per cell?  If so maybe you could pop the first item of the string array content or keep track of which index you should add.